# Is it possible to visit Qatar during the World Cup without buying a ticket?

Tags: event-based-effects, qatar

I'd like to visit Qatar to enjoy the atmosphere of the World Cup with tourists from all over the world, but I'm personally not a big fan of football and would rather not spend money on stadium tickets. Would entry to Qatar be possible during the World Cup if you haven't purchased any game tickets?

Normally my nationality is eligible for a 90-day visa-free entry to Qatar.

Comment: How well can you play football or build a stadium?

Comment: It is hard to imagine that Qatar would stop all other tourism during the World Cup…

Comment: Why would you not? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- World Cups have special conditions for entry usually. See my answer below.

Comment: You should probably edit some background into the question, otherwise it's a little weird to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like travel will be possible but you will need a special "Hayaa Card". [As per the FAQ](https://hayya.qatar2022.qa/web/hayya/faqs):

> **Will non-match ticket holders and business as usual visitors to Qatar
> need to apply for a Hayya Card during tournament time?**
>
> Yes. All travellers to Qatar – whether they intend to attend a match
> or not – will need to apply for a Hayya Card if they are visiting
> Qatar between 1 November 2022 and 23 January 2023.
>
> **Do I need a match ticket to apply for a Hayya Card?**
>
> Yes, at this stage we are inviting match ticket holders to apply for a
> Hayya Card. Further information in relation to non-ticket holders will
> be communicated in due course.

You can't get the Hayaa Card yet but you should be able to do so closer to November.

Answer (score 9):

If your nationality has visa-free access, outside of convincing the IO (Immigration Officer) that you're actually going for tourism (going for the WC without stadium ticket can look weird in their mind) and meeting the other regular formalities, nothing should prevent you from entering the country